# How to show Google Drive folder content dynamically on website

Tags: google-drive-api

does anybody know if it's possible to dynamically show the content of a Drive folder on a website? For example, I have a Drive folder with an pdf and two Google Docs. I want these three items displayed on the site in a list, like:

Document1.pdf
Document2.docx
Document3.docx

Now, If I upload a fourth document into the folder, the site should also display it:

Document1.pdf
Document2.docx
Document3.docx
Document4.docx

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Once you've read the documentation and started writing code, feel free to come back to SO with any problems you encounter.

Comment: Already found out, thanks. It's actually pretty simple via the iframe tag